# Run PHP script from command line?

Tags: command-line, php, php-cli

How can I simply run a PHP script in the command line? Also is it possible to run it like it would be if the URL was typed in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you have php installed, you run a PHP file using

```
/usr/bin/php /path/to/php/file.php
```

Or if your $PATH is set up properly to include /usr/bin, then simply

```
php /path/to/php/file.php
```

You can check if PHP is installed, by running

```
which php
```

Comment: Even better would be to just run $(which php) /path/to/php/file.php.  Then if php is installed somewhere else, say /usr/local/bin/php or something, then this will run from that bin location.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`php5`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/php5.1.html) command:

```
php5 /path/to/php/script
```

It's part of the `php5-cli` package.

The `php` command is part of [the alternatives system](https://superuser.com/questions/35275/ubuntus-etc-alternatives-mechanism), so it always points to something else. Depending on the version of PHP your script is in, it would be better to use the versioned command.

Running a PHP script the way it is called by a webserver is a bit complicated. The server sets up quite a few variables, which may or may not be used by the script. It would be much more simpler to run a webserver itself.

Comment: What is the difference to using just `php`